# Using Fat-Free PHP for Backbone.js routing with external Model.php files

Tags: backbone.js, routes, fat-free-framework

I'm very new to Fat-Free and Backbone.js. I've been searching and reading articles and searching and reading articles trying to find a way to route to individual PHP files containing the database communications. The code below works, and I can use it, but it seems hackish. Is there a way to call an external PHP file (in the server/models/ directory) and a specific method from the $f3-route(...) line?

```
<?php

// File: /index.php

define("PATH",1);

$f3 = require('server/fatfree/lib/base.php');

$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
require_once "server/models/{$uri[PATH]}.php";

$f3->route('GET /hello/@file', 'HelloModel->doSomething');
$f3->route('GET /project/@file', 'ProjectModel->doSomething');
$f3->route('GET /book/@file', 'BookModel->doSomething');

$f3->run();

?>
```

Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: Ok I found this Fat-Free way to load models dynamically...  

    $f3->set('AUTOLOAD', "server/models/");  

However, this will load _all_ models in that folder so I'm not sure I like this better than my hack above.

Comment: You could use Composer to generate an autoload file that will request your models dinamically when they are needed, more info here: [composer audoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Comment: you're wrong Locohost, it will not "load all models" instantly... moreover it will tell the spl_autoload_register function to search in that path for classes that you are using, but were not loaded already. So it is an AUTOLOADER... if you do not use one of the files in that path, if wont load anything...so, you don't have to worry.

Comment: @ikkez Interesting. So F3-set(AUTOLOAD... does sound like the right way to go. I'll edit my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `server/models` directory to the autoloader of F3 using the [autoloader](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#the-f3-autoloader) feature.

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','server/models/');
```

That way, the required source files of your classes will be loaded on demand. However, note that the files must be named the same as your class, i.e. class `Foo` has to be defined in `foo.php` or `Foo.php`. The case of the filename does not matter.